# Android app force closes soon as i open it on emulator

Tags: android

I went through similar kind of questions on older posts.. rectified them. Still getting force close problem. Please help.

Which of the following is correct?

```
Button continueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
```

or

`View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);`

And what's the difference between them ?

---

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.os.Bundle;


import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Sudoku extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Button continueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
       continueButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

       Button aboutButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.about_button);
       aboutButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

       Button newButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_game_button);
       newButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

       Button exitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
       exitButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

Comment: Do you have a stack trace on the force close?

Comment: See the `LogCat` for the exact exception, that will help pinpoint the problem. Both of the above are correct, depends on what you want to do (usually the first).

Comment: Check logcat for what exception is thrown ..

Answer (score 0):

Both is correct, because `Button` is a subclass of `View`. But you will typically have to use `Button` so you can add listeners and other stuff to it.

You should really have a look at the logcat output of you application. There you will find a stacktrace that will help you identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the way you set up your click listeners on your buttons. You use this but your activity class does not implement the interface. I advice you to do that instead:

```
 View.OnClickListener clickHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
  }

  Button continueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
  continueButton.setOnClickListener(clickHandler);+-
```